# Meaning of 'You wouldn't know good if it walked up and bit your nose off!'

Tags: meaning, phrases, translation

> “No,” he said, turning his burning face away from her.
>   “Yes. It's filthy. That aside, it's also no good.”
>   “You wouldn't know good if it walked up and bit your nose off!” he yelled, not caring.

I found literary translation of the last sentence with meaning like the man does not care how good it [the novel] was and sends the woman to hell with her notion of good.

Can anybody decompose the last sentence and/or rephrase it to make more clear such a translation?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221190/what-does-the-sentence-you-wouldnt-know-a-hospital-corner-if-it-bit-you-on-the

Comment: Perhaps "You wouldn't recognize 'good' if it walked up to you and kicked you in the butt!" might be better. "Bite your nose off" just does not work for me, for whatever reasons. Don

Comment: @rhetorician I'm sure Stephen King will take that under advisement ;-) https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cc5NCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22if+it+walked+up+and+bit+your+nose+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT7vuh9KLOAhXMDMAKHcY4B1QQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22if%20it%20walked%20up%20and%20bit%20your%20nose%20off%22&f=false

Comment: @Spagirl: I'm not that familiar with King's work, so I'll take your word for it. Don

Comment: @rhetorician thanks, your rephrase got the sense to me, I can mark as right answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You wouldn't know __ if it __ed you*** is a common idiom scheme (or [snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone)) which means that you wouldn't know or recognize something even if was very obvious.

For example:

> - ***[you wouldn't know __ if it hit you in the face](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wouldn't+know+if+it+hit+in+the+face)***
> - [***you wouldn't know __ if it hit you on the head***](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/558305685032096259/)
> - ***[you wouldn't know __ if it bit you on the arse](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221190/what-does-the-sentence-you-wouldnt-know-a-hospital-corner-if-it-bit-you-on-the)***
> - ***[you wouldn't know __ if you fell over it](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wouldn-t-know-sth-if-you-fell-over-one-it)***

The idea is that if something hit you in the face, bit you on the ass, or was such that you fell over it, then if would be pretty obvious to you what the thing was. But the sentence declares that even then, you are so oblivious that you still wouldn't know what the thing was.

Here are yet more variants:

> - ***you wouldn't know __ if it was right in front of you***
> - ***you wouldn't know __ if it was staring you in the face***
> - ***you wouldn't know __ if it was right under your nose***

You can embellish this kind of structure to make it more hyperbolic and colorful, as in your example of:

> - ***you wouldn't know __ if it walked up and bit your nose off***

This might be viewed as a play on the original structure as well as the expression ***[be right under your nose](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-right-under-your-nose)***, which means "to be in a place that you can clearly see."

Answer (score 1):

I like

> You wouldn't know "good" if it walked up to you and kicked you in the ____!

Fill in the blank with any word of your choosing (e.g., butt, ass, nads,* groin), keeping in mind, of course, who your audience happens to be!

*Short for gonads